# Weird animation when popping an UIViewController from an UINavigationController (IOS 5)

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I'm implementing a container view controller where a part of the screen is a view containing an `UINavigationController` view. My `viewDidLoad:` is something like this:

```
// ...
UIViewController *myNavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavigationController"];
[self addChildViewController:myNavigationController];
[self.myContainerView addSubview:myNavigationController.view];
[myNavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
// ...
```

No problems with rotations, and pushing new view controllers into the navigation controller works fine. But when the user taps on the Back `UIBarButtonItem`, not just `self.myContainerView` but the whole `self.view` animates upwards, similar to `kCATransitionFromBottom`, instead of the normal navigation controller pop animation. After a few more debugging I realized that my view controller's `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewWillAppear:` methods are getting called when popping from `myNavigationController`.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck. I'll appreciate if anyone can give an idea what's going and how to work around this.

**Edit:**
OK nevermind. I forgot to implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in one of my navigation controller's children. returning `YES` fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi, I think the thing to do it probably add an answer to your own question and mark it as answered so that it is easy for people to see that it has been answered. (though maybe you can't do that yet...)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll mark the question answered tomorrow once stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: I've been ripping my hair over the same problem. Such an obvious solution after I read this question. Thanks!

Comment: OMG thank you!!
This is an Apple bug tho, because it is not supposed to animated the application's window if this API is not been called. Don't you think?

Comment: Probably, or probably just undefined behavior. UINavigationController was designed to be full screen after all. I don't know if this still happens in iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to figure this out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK nevermind. I forgot to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in one of my navigation controller's children. returning YES fixed the problem.

Comment: I've came across the same issue and in my case was that I just forgot to *remove* - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;} from the tableViewController